# Up navigation can't bring back to Home Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation, kotlin-android-extensions

I have 3 Fragment on My Application (HomeFragment, NewsFragment,DetailFragment) the back button work as it should be. The up navigation works like the system back button do but the up navigation can't bring me back to the HomeFragment when it clicked on NewsFragment, while the back button can.

Here's my code :

MainActivity.kt

```
    package com.example.google_like

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.example.google_like.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }





}
```

HomeFragment.kt :

```
    package com.example.google_like.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.google_like.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        binding= FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {

            this.findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToNewsFragment())

        }

        return binding.root
    }


}
```

NewsFragment.kt:

```
package com.example.google_like.news

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.google_like.R
import com.example.google_like.databinding.FragmentNewsBinding
const val LOG_TAG = "NewsFragment"

class NewsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val newsViewModel : NewsViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
}
    lateinit var binding: FragmentNewsBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"onCreateView() called")
        binding = FragmentNewsBinding.inflate(inflater)
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"binding")

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.recycleView.adapter = NewsAdapter(NewsAdapter.OnClickListener{
        this.findNavController().navigate(NewsFragmentDirections.actionNewsFragmentToDetailFragment(it))
        })
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"recyclerView adapter")


        binding.viewModel = newsViewModel
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"binding.viewModel = newsViewModel")
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu,menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        newsViewModel.updateFilter(when(item.itemId){
            R.id.show_buy_menu -> MarsApiFilter.SHOW_BUY
            R.id.show_rent_menu -> MarsApiFilter.SHOW_RENT
            else -> MarsApiFilter.SHOW_ALL
        })
        return true
    }
}
```

DetailFragment.kt

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentDetailBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        val arguments = DetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).property
        val application = requireActivity().application

        val detailViewModelFactory = DetailViewModelFactory(arguments,application)
        val detailViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,detailViewModelFactory).get(DetailViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = detailViewModel

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.google_like">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BindingAdapter.kt (The RecyclerView are on the NewsFragment. This binding adapter also called when the Up Navigation clicked but the onCreateView() not. Normally, this binding adapter should be called when LiveData<List> (which passed as the parameter) changed .idk why this happen?)

```
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun RecyclerView.bindData(list: List<MarsProperty>?){
    Log.i("BindingAdapter","bindData() called")

        val adapter = this.adapter as NewsAdapter
        adapter.submitList(list)


}
```

Comment: Try `return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()`

Comment: i try it, still doesn't work